# Lenovo Flex 2-15 In Boot Menu Showing No HDD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, lenovo-laptop

So my computer was running very well, Lenovo Flex 15 running Windows 10. One day when I pressed on the start menu,computer froze and began to restart. Ever since that day in November 2016, (currently April 2017) I have been trying to find a solution to no avail, to the computer unable to run normally now. In BIOS setup it says no HDD or hard disk drive connected. I have never done anything like changing parts on the inside or even opened the back of the computer. Has anyone had this problem or know any solution to fix? Willing to reset to factory setting if it is needed.

Comment: Follow the [Hardware Maintenance Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_flex_2_14_flex_2_14d_flex_2_15_flex_2_15d_hmm.pdf) for this model and verify the HDD is connected correctly.

Comment: slow Windows can point to damaged HDD. looks like the HDD died now. remove the HDD and onsert it again, sometimes this can help, if not, the drive is dead. Buy a new HDD or better a SSD

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to either get stuck in to the hardware or take it to someone else to.

Your hard drive has either come unseated or has gone faulty. A few basic tools (screw driver and prying tool or guitar pic or credit card) and you are away.Searvhing "Lenovo flex 15 teardown" on YouTube  will provide a wealth of videos showing you exactly what to do. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HVYfAt1e7_A is the first one I came across.

If the hard drive is not loose, buy another one (or better, an SSD) from a computer store and install it, then reload OS.